# IntelliJ Ultimate/PhpStorm, showing code coverage results for Symfony2 project

Tags: intellij-idea, phpunit, code-coverage, phpstorm

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 11.1 which includes the goodies that comes with the latest PhpStorm.

I'm trying to get some things working with the new Code Coverage feature, but having a bit of trouble getting the coverage to show up in my IDE.

The unit testing is working 100%, I can even run the unit tests in debug mode, and trigger xdebug breakpoints etc, which I think is the most awesome thing since toast.

When I set **--coverage-html** the HTML coverage report is being generated ok, so it's clear that xdebug and phpunit are working nicely together.

The project is a Symfony2 project, which has it's PhpUnit configuration done in a file app/phpunit.xml.dist.

When I select Analyze > Show Code Coverage Data from the menu, I get a popup looking like this:

[image: Choose Coverage Suite to Display]

I'm clicking the [+] but not sure what I have to select, as the OK button on that dialog box is disabled all the time.

I understand that my Test Suite is defined inside the phpunit.xml.dist file, but not sure how to get IntelliJ to use that to figure out how to display code coverage.

I'd be really thrilled to be able to use this neat feature.

Comment: If you want to use this screen (but better use "Run with Coverage" button, unless you are using this to see coverage data from another system) -- you have to use [+] button and select **clover-xml** report generated by PHPUnit

Comment: Thanks for posting guys! And sorry for only getting back now. I ran a recent update on PHP Storm, and just re-ran the test with coverage again, and everything magically just started working! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran a recent update, and everything started working perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Please [check the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/monitoring-code-coverage-for-php-applications.html):

**To measure code coverage**

1. Prepare tests manually or have test classes generated.
2. Create a run configuration of the type PHPUnit.
3. On the main toolbar, select the PHPUnit run configuration in the Run/Debug Configurations drop-down list and click the **Run with Coverage** button.
4. Monitor the code coverage in the Coverage tool window.

Do you use the **Run with Coverage** button?

Comment: Is there a way to activate PHPUnit code coverage within IntelliJ IDEA with a similar UI to PHPStorm?

Comment: Never mind... I was using the wrong plugin (there are two coverage plugins)

Comment: The solution for me was to activate xdebug otherwise the coverage does not appear in the window.